# Add payload to vanilla JavaScript Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Is there a way to add payload to vanilla JavaScript event like you can do in jQuery?

```
// jQuery
$(document).trigger('event', payload);

// Vanilla JS
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('event', ???
```

I guess I have to use my own Event Bus of some kind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try utilizing `CustomEvent` , see [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

```js
function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log("detail:", e.detail);
}

window.addEventListener("build", eventHandler);

window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("build", {"detail": {"abc":123}}));
```